# How to drop outgoing edges except those with specific inVertices using Gremlin 3?

Tags: gremlin

I would like to drop outgoing edges from vertex `entity` if their inVertices are not contained in the list of `donttouch` ones.

I have a traversal like that:

```
g.V(id).as("entity")
 .V(id2).as("donttouch1")
 .V(id3).as("donttouch2")
 .outE("hasType").drop();
```

The above query has three issues:

- it needs to filter the edges to be dropped
- it needs somehow to backtrack to `entity` so the `outE("hasType")` edges come out of `entity` and not the last `donttouch`. I think in TinkerPop 2 it was possible with `back('x')` step
- it needs to return `entity` back after drop()

So I need something like that:

```
String[] donttouch= {"donttouch1","donttouch1"};

g.V(id).as("entity")
 .V(id2).as("donttouch1")
 .V(id3).as("donttouch2")
 .back("entity").outE("hasType")
 .where(not(inV().hasId(P.within(donttouch)))).drop().select("entity").next()
```

The list of `donttouch`s might be long so I would prefer to put them all at once and not as a conjunction of `neq`s

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the list of untouchable ids is already present in a list / set. In that case you can do:

```
g.withSideEffect("x", untouchableIds).
  V(id).outE("hasType").not(inV().id().where(within("x"))).drop()
```

Comment: can I still return entity after all this? Will I need to put another ```sideEffect()``` like that :
```g.withSideEffect("x", untouchableIds).sideEffect(
 V(id).as("entity").outE("hasType").not(inV().id().where(within("x"))).drop()).select("entity")``` ?

Comment: No, this doesn't make any sense and shouldn't even compile. If you want to have the entity emitted, then it's: `g.withSideEffect("x", untouchableIds).V(id).sideEffect(outE("hasType").not(inV().id().where(with‌​in("x"))).drop()))`.

Comment: yeah you are right I don't need to use ```as()``` and ```select()``` as the vertex already exists and has an ```id()```

Comment: up there I wanted to write:
```g.withSideEffect("x", untouchableIds).V(id).ad("entity").sideEffect(outE("hasType").not(inV().i‌​d().where(with‌​in("‌​x"))).drop())).se‌​lect("entity")``` this won't work either?

Comment: also what if this is in the mid of a traversal and not at the start? E.g I have already done other things on the graph and I have returned a ```GraphTraversal``` ?

Comment: The traversal you've mentioned above would work (if you fix the typo `ad` -> `as`). If this is done later in the traversal, it doesn't really change anything.

Comment: you mean it should work for later in the traversal too? Thanks

Comment: ```GraphTraversal``` doesn't have ```withSideEffect()``` only ```GraphTraversalSource``` does though..

Comment: Oh, that's what you meant. Yea, `withSideEffect` can only be called on the `GraphTraversalSource` and thus has to be known upfront. However, I think you can still mutate the collection (`untouchableIds`) from "outside" after using it in `withSideEffect`.